# Small Distributed Computing Cluster

Tags: linux, cluster, distributed-filesystem

I'm a high school student trying to build a linux cluster for a project (I have a bunch of decent computers slated for re-image this summer, so the tech department basically says as long as I don't physically break them I can do whatever.

Anyway, I don't really know anything about building a cluster, but I'm pretty good with Linux.

I need to know these things:
-What distro should I use? Does it even matter?
-What software can configure the cluster?
-On board or distributed FS?
-Any sites that can offer decent guides or how-tos?

Comment: What would be the purpose of the cluster?

Comment: Modern clusters are build for a specific purpose. Usually for web app, or data storage. Maybe you can try [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/).

Comment: As others have written, 'cluster' frequently implies parallel execution, which requires special codes or programming.  A different, but cool use of multiple computers working together is live fail-over of mirrored filesystems.  Take a minute and look into DRBD and clustered filesystems.  This might give you ideas too:   http://xenamo.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish, and what you mean by "Distributed Computing Cluster."  I did a similar thing once in Uni using old machines and [PVM](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/pvm/) that's the "Cluster" in the sense of a bunch of machines acting as one single computer to do parallel processing - think Beowulf clusters.  Of course, you will need code that is written to take advantage of this.

A good place to start, would be determining what you are looking to learn with this project.  I recommend reading the wikipedia article on [Parallel Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) for starters, and then refining your needs based on what you want to do.

A simple job queuing system (like [gearman](http://gearman.org/)) may be enough to get some cool results quickly.

The problem I had when I made a parallel computing cluster, was I didn't have anything to do on it, it just basically sat there, but it was a fun project and I learned quite a bit.  In any case, you are likely to learn quite a bit and have fun at the same time, regardless of what you choose to implement.

As far as choice of distributions, I would go with what I was most comfortable with, as you will likely need to install things from source.  Once you are comfortable getting everything setup, then you can look into finding a distribution that is tailored more towards your needs.  But any distribution should do.

What software to configure the cluster?  This depends entirely on what type of cluster you create.

On board vs. distributed FS?  Again, this depends on what the requirements for your cluster are.  Will each node be passing data back and forth among the other nodes? Will they operate as slaves with a single master? will they operatae completely independently?  These questions will start to inform your choices.  And of course, there are always trade offs.

Some other links that might prove interesting:

http://hadoop.apache.org/

http://www.csm.ornl.gov/oscar/

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/

http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Parallel_Computing/Programming/Environments/

http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Parallel_Computing/Beowulf/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple and non-developed suggestion; but maybe try a Plan 9 cluster?
http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/

Answer (score -1):

Try [Linux HA](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page) (High Availability) it is a freely available Linux cluster solution that works on several distributions.

It's probably only one of several solutions. I don't know how it compares with others, or even what its specific features are, I just know that some workmates swore by it for serious commercial software.